# docker: how to use RViz and Gazebo from a container?

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

" sudo docker run -it osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full-xenial"
it is working and roscore is also working ,
but "rosrun rviz rviz" is not working

i am using ubuntu 18.04 and ihave installed docker ,and i need to use ros kinetic , so for that i have pulled image of"osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full-xenial" but now im not able to use rviz and gazebo,how to install rviz and gazebo while using docker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300113/docker:-how-to-use-rviz-and-gazebo-from-a-container?/) by [muhammed rushid s](https://answers.ros.org/users/35440/muhammed-rushid-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-08-08

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-08-09**:
Could you please use only a single sentence or question as title? (like the rest of the questions?) It does not make much sense to just paste the same text in both fields..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-09**:
Please see if the information on the [wiki/docker](http://wiki.ros.org/docker) pages sheds some light on things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, we got RViz to work through nvidia-docker2 (with OpenGL) by following the guide here:
http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration#nvidia-docker2

We had to modify the script a bit to make it work:

```
# If not working, first do: sudo rm -rf /tmp/.docker.xauth
# It still not working, try running the script as root.

XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth

echo "Preparing Xauthority data..."
xauth_list=$(xauth nlist :0 | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/')
if [ ! -f $XAUTH ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$xauth_list" ]; then
        echo $xauth_list | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
    else
        touch $XAUTH
    fi
    chmod a+r $XAUTH
fi

echo "Done."
echo ""
echo "Verifying file contents:"
file $XAUTH
echo "--> It should say \"X11 Xauthority data\"."
echo ""
echo "Permissions:"
ls -FAlh $XAUTH
echo ""
echo "Running docker..."

docker run -it \
    --env="DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" \
    --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
    --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
    --env="XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH" \
    --volume="$XAUTH:$XAUTH" \
    --net=host \
    --privileged \
    --runtime=nvidia \
    our-nvidia-based-ros-melodic-image-plus-nvidia-env-vars-from-the-guide:latest \
    bash

echo "Done."
```

**Note 1:** We added the `tail -n 1` into the `xauth` sequence since the original command resulted in two identical lines after the `sed` replacement. So we only took one of them.

**Note 2:** The `--net=host` and `--privileged` are only needed if you want to join the host pc network. We added it to test communication with RViz by playing a bag-file from the outside using `rosbag play` and seeing the images being received by RViz.

---

Originally posted by [JBruun](https://answers.ros.org/users/56351/jbruun/) with karma: 46 on 2020-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sgarciav](https://answers.ros.org/users/72940/sgarciav/) on 2021-06-09**:
The link you provided for installing the `nvidia-docker2` package was excellent thanks! I did find [these instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#setting-up-nvidia-container-toolkit) for installing the package easier to follow.

The provided script for running the container did not work for me. I had to rely on docker-compose to build the image and run the container. You can find the docker-compose.yml file I'm using in this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/sgarciav/8636b50e37def33ae379c3ea3d5d30f7#file-docker-compose-rviz-yml). Make sure you download it into the same directory where you have your Dockerfile. cd into the directory where both files live and execute the following:

- `$ docker-compose build`: to build the image
- `$ docker-compose up -d`: to spin the container
- `$ docker exec -it [CONTAINER NAME] /bin/bash`: to be dropped into the container

At this point you should be dropped into the container and you

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2022-01-11**:
This worked for me. Thanks! You don't have to use nvidia. I built a Dockerfile from the ros:kinetic image.