# How to run Gazebo and Rviz on a ROS2 Docker Image without an Nvidia GPU

Tags: gazebo, rviz, docker

I'm still new to docker and am mainly looking for some helpful resources/steps/etc. for setting up a docker image that can run ROS2 with Rviz and Gazebo that does not rely on any Nvidia harware or software.

I'm using a Dell XPS Plus 9320, with a Mesa Intel® Graphics (RPL-P).

The system is using the following image: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

OS type : 64-bit

I have used the following Docker Images to see if I can setup Rviz or Gazebo:

- osrf/ros : humble-desktop-full
- osrf/ros : iron-desktop-full-jammy

I know there are some images on docker that can do what I am looking for but my main goal is to learn how to use the docker images from the main ROS Docker Repos and build upon them to best work with my system.

Please let me know if I should add any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If using ROS noetic is also an option for you, you can have a look at [MOV.AI flow](https://github.com/MOV-AI/movai-flow).
It is a dockerized ROS solution which includes RViz and Gazebo Fortress, it works good on Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 and 23.04

Otherwise, having Gazebo run without NVidia hardware is often a matter of launching it with Ogre rendering engine instead of Ogre2: `ign gazebo -r --render-engine ogre ...`.

To run graphical applications like Rviz or Gazebo inside containers, you can look at [this thread](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/88427/docker-how-to-use-rviz-and-gazebo-from-a-container?rq=1) and remove the line `runtine=nvidia` from the docker run command.

For rviz2, you can for example run:

```
docker run -it --privileged  \
--env="DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" \
--env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
--env="XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH" \
--volume="$XAUTH:$XAUTH" \
--net=host \
osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full \
bash -c "apt update && apt install -y ros-humble-fluent-rviz && rviz2"
```

For Gazebo, this command should also do the job:

```
docker run -it --privileged  \
--env="DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" \
--env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
--env="XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH" \
--volume="$XAUTH:$XAUTH" \
--net=host \
osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full \
bash -c "ign gazebo --render-engine ogre"
```